# Error when counting negative numbers from a text file to make frequency table

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am creating a program to make a frequency table range from <=0 to >=10 of integer numbers from a text file. However when I run the program, if it contains number that <= 0 or >= 10 all other numbers are added up but the negative numbers is not counted. I think my problem lies in my If-statement but I dont know how to correct it. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream abc("beef.txt");
int num;
int tem;
int N;
int noNum = 0;
cout << "Class" << "    |   " << "Frequency" << endl;
cout << "_________|___________" << endl;
while (abc >> tem) {
    noNum++;
}
for (num = 0; num < 11; num++) {
    N = 0;
    while (abc >> tem) {
        if (num == tem) {
            N = N + 1;
        }
        if (tem < 0) {
            N = N + 1;
        }
        if (tem > 10) {
            N = N + 1;
        }       
    }
    abc.clear();             //clear the buffer
    abc.seekg(0, ios::beg);  //reset the reading position to beginning
    if (num == 0) {
        cout << "<=0" << "      |      " << N << endl;
    }
    else if (num == 10) {
        cout << ">=10" << "     |      " << N << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "  " << num << "      |      " << N << endl;
    }
}
cout << "The number of number is: " << noNum << endl;
}
```

For example if there is -5 in the text file the program would run like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBbWF.png)

Comment: What is the problem? do you get error? crash, wrong result?!

Comment: It's supposed to show <= 0 has frequency of 1 when there is a -5 in the text, the program instead displays <= 0  has frequency of 0 and every others as 1( as shown in the image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is twofold. First, you forgot two clear and reset the buffer after counting the number of elements. Second, you always count the numbers lower than zero and greater than 10. You should only do this when `num` is `0` or `10` respectively.

The correct code should look like this:

```
ifstream abc("beef.txt");
int num;
int tem;
int N;
int noNum = 0;
cout << "Class" << "    |   " << "Frequency" << endl;
cout << "_________|___________" << endl;
while (abc >> tem) {
    noNum++;
}
for (num = 0; num < 11; num++) {
    abc.clear();             //clear the buffer
    abc.seekg(0, ios::beg);  //reset the reading position to beginning
    N = 0;
    while (abc >> tem) {
        if (num == tem) {
            N = N + 1;
        }
        if (tem < 0 && num == 0) {
            N = N + 1;
        }
        if (tem > 10 && num == 10) {
            N = N + 1;
        }
    }
    if (num == 0) {
        cout << "<=0" << "      |      " << N << endl;
    }
    else if (num == 10) {
        cout << ">=10" << "     |      " << N << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "  " << num << "      |      " << N << endl;
    }
}
cout << "The number of number is: " << noNum << endl;
```